# How to navigate out of a Modal in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a button on the very first page of my webapp. on clicking this webapp a modal is opened which is a form. On Submit of this form, an API is called which will update the DB and no response is expected since this is a one time entry.

Since this is the first page, using history.push('/') does nothing. The Submit button just remains clicked. How do I navigate out of this page?

```
const addGroupSubmitHandler = async(event) => {
            event.preventDefault()
            const submittedValues = (Object.values(getValueData))
            try {
                const responseData = await sendRequest(
                  'http://localhost:5000/admin/activeTournament',
                  'PATCH',
                  JSON.stringify({
                    submittedValues
                  }),
                  {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                  }
                );
                history.push('/')
              } catch (err) {
                console.log(err)
              }       
    }
```

Comment: If it is a modal then you should close the modal once the API is fired . history.push('/') is to move to a different page. How are you opening the modal ? are you using state , if yes then toggle the state .

Comment: Hey man actually I am new to react and just getting the grips of the whole state logic. The below answer is what i was looking for. I guess I will just build it into my muscle memory soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use React state like `const [popup, setPopup] = useState(false)`
Modal is only rendered when popup is true
So, the flow should be like:

1. Click the button, `setPopup(true)` to render modal
2. Add `setPopup(false)` at the end of `addGroupSubmitHandler` so when the form is submitted it will turn the modal off.